# loopback model json array of objects strict filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm using strongloop loopback v3 REST API with mongoDB as datasource. My model `order.json` is

```json
{
  "name": "order",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": true,
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "orderNo": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lines": {
      "type": [
        {
          "type": {
            "description": "string",
            "quantity": "number"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

I set `"strict": true` so that [the model accepts only predefined properties](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html). But this **does not work** for properties in the array `lines`.

I.E. if you post this object to the API you get an ValidationError (Code 422) as expected:

```json
{
  "orderNo": "xyz",
  "someOtherProp": "hello",
  "lines": [
    {
      "description": "abc",
      "quantity": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

But if you post this JSON object loopback saves the object to mongoDB

```json
{
  "orderNo": "xyz",
  "lines": [
    {
      "description": "abc",
      "quantity": 5,
      "someOtherProp": "hello"
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is about if there are any flags to be set in the model JSON to validate an array of objects? Or do I have to validate the nested documents by my own via the `order.js` [model extension file](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-extension-file.html)?

Comment: You can use [AJV JSON Schema Validator](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) to validate model properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define the `lines` as another model and make it relation with type `embedsMany` in `order` model.

**lines model**

```
{
    "name": "line",
    "base": "Model",
    "strict": true,
    "idInjection": true,
    "properties": {
      "description": {
        "type": "string"
      },
     "quantity":{
       "type":"number"
      }
  }
}
```

**order model**

```
{
    "name": "order",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "strict": true,
    "idInjection": true,
    "options": {
      "validateUpsert": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "orderNo": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {
       "lines":{
        "type": "embedsMany",
        "model": "line",
        "property": "lines"
       }
    },
    "acls": [],
    "methods": {}
}
```

this way loopback will validate `line` model

Comment: absolute correct. I overlooked this site: [Embedded models and relations](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Embedded-models-and-relations.html). But make sure to use 'base: "Model"' in the embedded definition.

Comment: yes you are right @LonelyIsland i will edit the answer.